# Understanding exec

Tags: linux, scripting, php, fdisk, exec

I need to understand the following script sequence.

```
$command .= "n\n\n\n\nt\n7\nc\nw\n";                        
exec("echo -e \"{$command}\" | /sbin/fdisk {$kernelDevice}");
```

I can't figure out which command is really executed with the `exec`.

Comment: Is that an excerpt of a perl script?

Comment: Looks like Perl. Is there something in particular you're wondering? You dp know what `exec` usually does?

Comment: it is php. What an exec does is ok for me, but I can´t understand which command in detail is invoked by the exec

Comment: Is this PHP run from a web interface? Please, please say "no".

Answer (score 2):

The string of characters is given to `fdisk` one by one. Each `\n` is a return and the letters have specific meanings to fdisk:

```
n   add a new partition (default values selected with \n)
t   change partition type (a value of 7 is selected)
c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
w   write table to disk and exit
```

In short: make new partition (use available space), change partition type to 7, toggle the dos flag, write and exit.